# Local file inclusion vulnerability in spring java

Tags: java, spring, security, configuration

I have a web application in java using spring MVC framework. Yesterday, security team shared an URL to exploit the local file inclusion vulnerability(exposing web.xml on the browser).

I am not able to figure out where to look for the suspected area. Is it in the spring configuration or in the JSP file.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/context-beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>



    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:spring/web-app-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and returned jsp.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>SignUp</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/services/resources/css/fa-fonts.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/services/resources/css/common.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/services/resources/css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/services/resources/css/header.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/services/resources/js/lib/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/services/resources/js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="services-sec js-popDiv" id="loaderStrip" style="display: none;">
        <div class='services-loaderDiv'>
            <h2 class="bold">Please Wait </h2>
            <i class="services-loader-dot"></i>
        </div>
        </section>
        <jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: My magic ball told me the vulnerability is line#42 of the code you have not posted)

Comment: I can not share the whole project but the web.xml and and JSP file.

Comment: *security team shared an URL*: so, what is this URL? What is mapped to this URL?

Comment: Your application sounds old, which app server are you using? Is your application running in debug mode in prod env?

Comment: @JBNizet /services/getFrm?page=..%2f..%2fWEB-INF%2fweb.xml%3bx%3d

Comment: So, see what Spring controller is mapped to this URL, and change your design in order to stop accepting arbitrary paths as parameters.

Comment: @Avinash Tomcat-7.54, Not in Debug Mode

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it is not a Problem of your configuration but of the functionality of your application:
If you have some filename which can be given by user, you have to check if it is a correct filename. e.g. if you have a file upload Dialog and a user selects the filename it should not be something like "../../web.xml" but something like "file.txt" You can use uploadName = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadName); to check if String uploadname is only a file or also contains back traversing paths, like "../"